# Jquery how to set background-image independent from request

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-image

I am trying to set a background image for a website that doesn't change with request but should change only with time.

for example I want to keep every single image on the screen for 6 hours.

Currently my code is:

```
var $my_div = $('.picture-div');
var $image_paths = gon.photo_paths;
var $current = 0;
var $picture_time = 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var timeout;

function nextImage() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  var $cur_path = $image_paths[$current = ++$current % $image_paths.length];
  $my_div.css('background-image', 'url(' + $cur_path + ')');
  timeout = setTimeout(nextImage, $picture_time);
}
nextImage();
```

image_paths: array of the asset paths (Rails, with the help of "gon" gem)

The problem with the above code is it restart itself with each request. So how can I make it "request" independent but time dependent.

Comment: use setInterval and clearInterval instead setTimeout/clearTimeout

Comment: Can't you just check the timeout variable. if not null then do not clearTimeout and setTimeout when null.

Comment: @rontornambe it doesn't work because timeout will be undef with each request anyway.. and Venkata Panga doesn't matter,

Comment: timeout is not the issue. clearTimeout can be passed null or undefined. @bkdir can you explain the issue more clearly